# Turning off local db backup with rubber, while still backing up to S3

Tags: database-backups, rubber

I've uncommented the `backup_bucket:` line in rubber.yml, and now my db gets backed up both locally and to my S3 bucket. I would like to have my db only backing up to S3. Is there a way to disable local backup, while still keeping S3 backup?

Comment: Why don't you want the local backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to do this, was add the following to the db backup crontab job (config/rubber/role/db/crontab):

```
&& rm -rf /mnt/db_backups/*
```